# Error in Matlab: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch

Tags: matlab

I have this problem and can't figure out what the problem is.

```
for i=1:e
    s  = size(E_{i});
    r2 = s(1);
    E_{i}(1:r2,3) = (E_{i}(:,2))/(E_{i}(:,1));
end
```

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Comment: E_ is a cell array with varying sizes of arrays, thus the size function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `/`, which is matrix division. Try using `./` (element-wise division), so that you get as many output elements as there are in input operands.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking at what size "(E_{i}(:,2))/(E_{i}(:,1));" is? Hint: you probably meant to use `./` instead of `/`.

Comment: Well spotted, it was indeed that (./)